# Magento 2: Watching changes in env.php file

Tags: magento2, log

Is there any way to watch changes in `env.php` file? I would like to log all changes into some file.

Comment: If you use GIT this file can be put in GIT and there you can easily see the changes following the commit

Comment: @St3phan Although this is in `.gitignore`, somehow it is changed. We are *suspecting* that somehow some extension is changing this file. Adding it into GIT will only show me what is added, or removed. I would like to see time of change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this class `Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig\Writer`. It is responsible to write configurations to `env.php` file. It has a `saveConfig()` method, and writing a before plugin for this method will do the job.